# Is that code PSNR correct?

Tags: matlab, 3d, mesh

I want to calculate the PSNR between two 3D surface meshes X and Y and I konw that `PSNR=20*log(bounding box diagonal/RMSE)`

```
RMSE=max((d(X,Y),d(Y,X))
```

and `d(X,Y)=sqrt (1/area(x))*integral(d(x,Y)^2 dx))`.
Can you tell me if my code is correct because it gives abnormal negative values.

```
//distance between two points
function d = distance(p,p2 )
diffx=p(1)-p2(1);
diffy=p(2)-p2(2);
diffz=p(3)-p2(3);
d=sqrt(diffx^2+diffy^2+diffz^2);
// Distance point-surface : 
function min = min_distance(p,v )
    m=1000000;
    for i=1:size(v,1)% v has n rows and 3 columns (x,y,z)
    point=v(i,:);
    d=distance(p,point);
    if (d<m)
    m=d;
    end 
    end
    min=m;
    end
//Distance surface-surface
function s= som_min_dist(v1,v2)
s=0;
for i=1: size(v1,1);
p=v1(i,:);
s=s+min_distance(p,v2)^2;
end
end
//RMSE: Root mean square error = max (Drmse(Q,R),Drmse(Q,R))
[volume1,area1]=volume_area_3D(v1)// this function is already verified 
[volume2,area2]=volume_area_3D(v2)
      d1=som_min_dist(v1,v2)
      d2=som_min_dist(v2,v1)
      rmse1= sqrt((1/area1)*d1)
      rmse2= sqrt((1/area2)*d2)
      rmse=max(rmse1,rmse2)
      psnr=20*log(bounding_box_diagonal/rmse)//bounding_box is alreay calculated
```